# Diferencia entre usar setter - getter y constructor

Tags: java

estoy repasando un poco la programación orientada a objetos, pero hay una cosa que no entiendo bien, y es para que utilizar el constructor o utilizar getters y setters para darle valores a los objetos en cuestion.

Para empezar entiendo que el Getter se debe utilizar para poder ver el dato, ya que si lo encapsulamos  no nos deja acceder a el.

Pero el setter  no lo entiendo muy bien, por que en teoría no se le puede pasar también a través del constructor las variables?  Por que entonces crear el setter? Para poder editarlo una vez ya creado?

Si algo que dije no se entiende, lo explico de nuevo

```
public class Persona {

    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
    
    public Persona(String nombre, int edad) {
    
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad=edad;
    }
    
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
     public String getNombre() {
        String nombre = this.nombre;
        
        return nombre;
    }
}
```

```
public class CrearPersona {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    

        Persona persona = new Persona("Fernando",12);
        
        System.out.println(persona.getNombre());
        
        persona.setNombre("Luis");
        
        System.out.println(persona.getNombre());
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el mismo motivo: la `encapsulacion`.

Se supone que todas las propiedades de tu objeto son privadas, y solo puedes acceder con un metodo publico (`setter`)

Ademas, en este `setter`, puedes poner tus propias restricciones, como por ejemplo que numero de DNI sean cifras y números o lo que se te pase por la cabeza.

---

Con lo del constructor tienes razón, puedes pasar por parámetros, pero imagina que es un parámetro no conocido.

No te queda otra que en el constructor, crearlo sin ese parámetro (o con sobrecarga) y crear un `setter`.

> **EJEMPLO**
>
> Nace un niño, invocas al constructor, le pasas: sexo, peso, altura.
> (objeto creado)
>
> El niño se hace mayor y le dan DNI, y el objeto ya lo creaste -->
> setter de DNI
>
> ```
> SetDni()
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Exacto, tu lo has dicho.
La idea de los setters es poder modificar el estado interno de tu objeto, una vez que ya ha sido construido.
Muchas veces no queremos que ese estado se modifique, entonces podemos no agregar setters, y hacer todas las variables de instancia `final`, en principio eso haría que nuestros objetos sean inmutables, una vez construídos, no sería posible cambiar el estado.
Pero hay que ser cuidadoso, porque algunas propiedades pueden no ser inmutables en sí, por ejemplo una variable de tipo `java.util.Date`, aunque sea `final`, si es accesible desde afuera de la clase porque justamente tiene un getter, se podría cambiar, no el objeto, sino el valor del mismo.

Por ejemplo:

```
import java.util.Date;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fechita fechita = new Fechita(new Date()); // inicializado con la fecha y hora actual
        Date fecha = fechita.getFecha();
        fecha.setTime(34544554845L); //le cambiamos a cualquier otra fecha
        System.out.printf("%Tc", fechita.getFecha()); //la fechita ha cambiado
    }
}


class Fechita {
    private final Date fecha;

    public Fechita(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }
}
```

Aquí aunque fecha es final, igual se pudo modificar su valor.

Answer (score 1):

Los getters y los setters se utilizan para acceder a los atributos de forma controlada, asi ninguna clase puede modificar desde fuera de los mismos los valores de dichos atributos, es un principio de encapsulación, al mismo tiempo, puedes codificar ciertas condiciones o realizar cambios en los datos de entrada antes de pasarlos al atributo de la clase.

El constructor se utiliza para definir que sucede en el momento que creamos una instancia de una clase mediante el operador new,el constructor nos permite asignar valores por defecto a los campos o llamar a otro constructor o metodo si asi se desea.

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola!
Sabemos que el  encapsulamiento en Java sirve para ocultar
métodos y atributos(variables) de una clase. Esto resulta útil
al momento de compartir nuestras clases con otro programadores.

Sin embargo, en ocasiones es necesario o requerido el otorgar
acceso a algunos atributos de nuestra clase sin eliminar el
encapsulamiento, ya que el haber compartido el acceso no
es para que sea considerado de manera pública.

Para estas situaciones existen los métodos setter() y getter()

Estos métodos sirven para dar acceso a los atributos de una clase
que están encapsulados de manera privada con la finalidad de obtener
datos de los atributos encapsulados.

El método setter nos sirve para asignar un valor a un atributo de
nuestra clase encapsulada de manera privada. Esto se hace de manera
directa con este método. Como éste método no retorna nada debe
contener la palabra void en su estructura, y siempre debe recibir un parámetro
de entrada.

Y el método getter, accede a la clase para retornarnos el valor de algún
atributo que queramos. Este método si debe retornar un valor por lo
cual la estructura de este método debe contener el tipo de valor
que vamos a retornar con ese método.

Comment: Acompaña tu texto con un poquito de codigo para que sea mas facil para el.

Answer (score 0):

El definir un atributo en el constructor para lo que te sirve es para garantizar que si el objeto se crea, obligatoriamente va a tener ese atributo definido.

```
public class ConConstructor {

  private String parametro;

  public ConConstructor(String parametro) {
     this.parametro = parametro;
  }

  public String getParametro() {
     return parametro;
  }

}


public class SinConstructor {

  private String parametro;

  public String getParametro() {
     return parametro;
  }

  public setParametro(String parametro) {
     this.parametro = parametro;
  }

}
```

Fijate lo que pasa si llamas a getParametro despues de crear los objetos:

```
ConConstructor obj1 = new ConConstructor("mi parametro");
System.out.println(obj1.getParametro()); // Escribe: mi parametro

SinConstructor obj2 = new SinConstructor();
System.out.println(obj2.getParametro()); // Escribe: null
obj2.setParametro("mi parametro");
System.out.println(obj2.getParametro()); // Escribe: mi parametro
```

Como ves, si entre la creación y el setter accedes a ese atributo, va a estar indefinido.

Esto no quiere decir que siempre haya que definir los atributos del constructor, hay casos que por la naturaleza del programa que estés haciendo, haya algunos atributos que tengan que estar indefinidos en el momento de crear el objeto y haya que darles ese valor más adelante. El setter también te sirve si el valor del atributo tiene que cambiarse varias veces, ya que el constructor solo se ejecuta una vez para un objeto dado, pero el setter se puede llamar tantas veces como haga falta.

Comment: Creo que el OP no pregunta esto, pregunta para que se usa, no como.